# If a file has a command copied in it, how can I extract that command from the file onto the active command prompt in a terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

If I have a rather large complex command, I often just cat it into a file. This works well in an SSH terminal where I can use the client copy and paste. But if I am directly on the terminal I don't have that luxury.  Cat'ing the file just outputs it once and then kicks back to the active prompt. I'm looking for something that will kick that file content onto the active prompt so I can scroll back and make minor tweaks and run it again.

Comment: Edit a file using an editor?

Comment: `history -r file` will add the file contents to your history, from where they can be recalled, editted, and executed

Comment: I know you want to modify it, but in case you want to run that command unchanged, `$(cat FILECONTAININGCOMMAND)` or `$(<FILECONTAININGCOMMAND)`.

Comment: If it's just the file, why not run it as a script after editing as you please in an actual editor? `nano filename; $SHELL filename`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after rereading your question I think what you require can be
achieved in Bash using `shell-expand-line` built-in readline
keybinding. Let's first create a sample FILE containing a shell
command:

```
echo hi user > FILE
```

Now type:

```
$(cat FILE)
```

but instead of pressing Enter press
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> - the line will be
changed to:

```
hi user
```

but not executed. The final effect will be as if you typed it manually.